# Eclispe pydev settings module could not be found

Tags: django, eclipse, module, settings, pydev

I keep trying to set up a project with Eclipse Neon Release Candidate 3(4.6.ORC3) and PyDev 5.1.1 and keep having the same problem. Going to Project > Properties > PyDev-Django screen, I keep getting the same error Settings Module could not be found. I have tried everything to try to fix this error, including manually filling in the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE manually. Nothing works. The problem really exist because manage.py tests and runserver return the same error. The settings.py file exists and is in the correct place in the project directory. I am dead in the water untill I get this fixed.

Note: I upgraded the system to Neon 4.6 and PyDev 5.1.2 . I still have the same problem

Using Debian Linux Stretch with KDE Desktop.

Please help.

Gary R.

Comment: Why are you still using a Release Candidate version of Eclipse Neon? The final release came out in June and is based on RC4a.

Answer (score 3):

**Before adding the project to the python path**

[image]
**Adding the python path to the project:**
[image]
**now pythonpath is added to the project**
[image]

**After adding python path to the project settings module is found**
[image]

I am using: django 1.10, pydev 5.2

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the PyDEV PYTHONPATH settings includes the directory where manage.py lives.

Comment: The PyDev-Pythonpath SourceFolder window contains: /$(PROJECT_DIR_NAME)/src. I added /$(PROJECT_DIR_NAME)/src/archivesii . This did not solve the problem.

Comment: Manage.py usually sits in the /$(PROJEDT_DIR_NAME) but you haven't shown us your project layout.